# Lucene Abstract Method Error when executing a multisearch in Elasticsearch 2.2.0

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

The queries are for two words ---> `"word1"` and `"\"another word\""`. I add two multi-search queries to a `MultiSearchRequestBuilder` and then execute the query, but I get this response:

```
{
  "responses" : [ {
    "took" : 22,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 6,
      "successful" : 4,
      "failed" : 2,
      "failures" : [ {
        "shard" : 2,
        "index" : "elasticsearch.test",
        "node" : "99LdzvW_T0aBY4UOzNHAIA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "abstract_method_error",
          "reason" : "org.apache.lucene.search.TwoPhaseIterator.matchCost()F"
        }
      } ]
    },
    "hits" : {
      "total" : 0,
      "max_score" : null,
      "hits" : [ ]
    }
  }, {
    "took" : 18,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 6,
      "successful" : 5,
      "failed" : 1,
      "failures" : [ {
        "shard" : 2,
        "index" : "elasticsearch.test",
        "node" : "rdK2996KQz-H0khDgW7mKg",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "abstract_method_error",
          "reason" : "org.apache.lucene.search.TwoPhaseIterator.matchCost()F"
        }
      } ]
    },
    "hits" : {
      "total" : 0,
      "max_score" : null,
      "hits" : [ ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

The issue is that it works in ES 2.1.1 but not in ES 2.2.0!!

What is the issue here?

Comment: do you use an embedded node, or the "official" zip ?

Comment: This error actually comes from a test case.

Comment: I use the official zip

Comment: Check the version of the library "lucene-core" embedded in your test. It should be 5.4.1

Comment: @JérémieB That issue that you were talking was submitted by me. But I thought maybe I have done something wrong. So, I upgraded to 2.1 but then I thought let me try to upgrade to 2.2 but that error still persists.
Yeah, I'll check the lucene-core version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TwoPhaseIterator.matchCost` has been added in Lucene 5.4 in this issue: [LUCENE-6276](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6276).

- ElasticSearch 2.1 use Lucene 5.3.x
- ElasticSearch 2.2 use Lucene 5.4.x

You have probably the wrong dependency on Lucene in your test, a version < 5.4